# Calling a servlet from the URL

Tags: java, servlets

I have created a servlet with an endpoint as below-

```
@WebServlet("/Email_token_Auth")
public class Email_auth extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

When I am hitting my url `http://localhost:8080/Email_token_Auth` its throwing 404 not found error.

How do we call a servlet from a url ?

Comment: The syntax for specifying the URL should work as you specified it. You didn't specify a context path in the URL you called, does your app have one?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/project_name/Email_token_Auth

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like bottom. Project name may need to add

```
http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/Email_token_Auth
```